# Simple format of ticks on top of plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to wrap my head around ticks, labels, etc. but I find it extremely confusing. I've tried a bunch of alternatives from the docs and over here (`twiny`, formatters, etc.) for this simple code, that should show station names on the secondary X-axis, without success. Any help is appreciated, I don't see what's missing at all.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FixedFormatter, FuncFormatter

#plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
#plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True

x_axis1 = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 5.5, 6.0, 10.5, 15.0, 15.5]
y_axis1 = [60.0, 80.0, 70.0, 60.0, 70.0, 50.0, 80.0, 100.0, 80.0, 60.0, 50.0]
x_axis2 = [0.0, 2.8, 10.4, 15.6]
y_axis2 = ['First Station', 'Second Station', 'Third Station', 'Last station']

host = host_subplot(111)
host.set_xlabel("Distance [km]")
host.set_ylabel("Speed [km/h]")
host.tick_params(
    axis="x", which='minor', direction="in", width=2, length=5, labelsize=10, color="red"
)
host.step(x_axis1, y_axis1, label="Speed")

x_formatter = FixedFormatter(y_axis2)
x_locator = FixedLocator(x_axis2)
host.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(x_formatter)
host.xaxis.set_minor_locator(x_locator)
#host.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
#host.xaxis.set_tick_params(labeltop='on')

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqCAw.png) similar to what you're getting?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Edit: Also just realized that the station index is offset by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you are looking for the [`secondary_xaxis()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html) functionality. This adds a second x-axis for which the ticks have some fixed relation with the main ticks. A related function is `twiny()`, which creates second x-axis with independent tick positions.

For standard plots (as in this case), `host_subplot` isn't needed. It is quite complex and doesn't have an easily-understood documentation.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FixedFormatter

x_axis1 = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 5.5, 6.0, 10.5, 15.0, 15.5]
y_axis1 = [60.0, 80.0, 70.0, 60.0, 70.0, 50.0, 80.0, 100.0, 80.0, 60.0, 50.0]
x_axis2 = [0.0, 2.8, 10.4, 15.6]
y_axis2 = ['First Station', 'Second Station', 'Third Station', 'Last station']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel("Distance [km]")
ax.set_ylabel("Speed [km/h]")
ax.step(x_axis1, y_axis1, label="Speed")
ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis('top') # alternatively, set it at 'bottom'
ax2.tick_params(axis="x", which='major', direction="in", width=2, length=5, labelsize=10, color="red")

x_locator = FixedLocator(x_axis2)
x_formatter = FixedFormatter(y_axis2)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_locator) # it's best to first set the locator and only then the formatter
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)
# optionally add vertical lines at each of the station positions
for x in x_axis2:
    ax.axvline(x, color='lime', ls=':', lw=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: `step()` has a parameter [`where`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html) to decide whether the step ends (the default, `'pre'`) or starts (`'post'`) with the changed value. Maybe `ax.step(..., where='post')` is closer to the intended meaning of the data? (`where='mid'` is a third option).

A secondary axis doesn't support all functions of a normal axis. If a function such as `ax2.axvline()` is needed, you can replace `ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis()` by a `twiny` and explicitly set the x limits:

```
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Since I plan to use Checkbuttons, is there a way to draw the vertical lines as part of the secondary axis instead? `ax2` doesn't implement `vline` or `axvline`, and dynamically changing  `ax2.tick_params`'s `length` seems quite cumbersome. The updated code is  [here](https://gist.github.com/danicc097/ed375179abce65364fd41ef9d00b8ea2) and [how it looks now](https://i.imgur.com/nnm05bI.png).

Comment: I added a comment about using `twiny`, in which case you need to explicitly set the x limits.

Comment: Works perfectly now, I updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/danicc097/ed375179abce65364fd41ef9d00b8ea2). Thanks again!